# print the selected choice name as well

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am unable to place the print command for printing the name of selected choice. The code is as follows:

```
import dpkt
from dpkt.ip import IP
from dpkt.ethernet import Ethernet
import struct
import socket
import csv
def ip_to_str(address):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(address)

f = open('ipp.pcap', 'rb')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
loop = 1
while loop ==1:
    print("Select IPv4 Header Fields:")
    print ("1) Ver")
    print ("2) HeaderLength")
    print ("3) Total Length")
    print ("4) Exit")
    ch = input("Choose your option:")
    choice = ch.split(',')
    for ts, buf in pcap: 
         eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
         if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
            continue
        ip = eth.data
        Length = "%d" % (ip.len)
        TTL = "%d" % (ip.ttl)
        ver = ip.v
        hdrlen = dpkt.ip.IP_HDR_LEN
        ff = ''
        for k in range(0,len(choice)):
            if int(choice[k]) == 1:
                ff=ff + ', '+ str(ver)
                #print ver 
            if int(choice[k]) == 2:
                #print hdrlen
                ff=ff + ',  '+str(hdrlen)
            if int(choice[k]) == 3:
                ff=ff+ ',  '+ str(Length)
            if int(choice[k]) == 4:
                loop = 0
        print ff
```

whose output is as follows:

```
Select IPv4 Header Fields:
1) Ver
2) HeaderLength
3) Total Length
4) Exit
Choose your option:'1,2,3'
, 4,  20,  60
, 4,  20,  60
, 4,  20,  52
, 4,  20,  193
, 4,  20,  341
```

But I want that it should have the headers name at top like as follows, so expected output is:

```
Select IPv4 Header Fields:
1) Ver
2) HeaderLength
3) Total Length
4) Exit
Choose your option:'1,2,3'
, Ver, HeaderLength, Total Length
, 4,  20,  60
, 4,  20,  60
, 4,  20,  52
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: store your choices in a `dict` and you can use them for printing later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code after the line `choice = ch.split(',')`

```
dict = {'1':'Ver', '2':'HeaderLength', '3':'TotalLength'}
print(', '.join([dict[i] for i in choice if i in dict.keys()]))
```

I would recommend you replace your while loop with the following:

```
while loop:
    print("Select IPv4 Header Fields:")
    print ("1) Ver")
    print ("2) HeaderLength")
    print ("3) Total Length")
    print ("4) Exit")
    choice = [i.strip() for i in input("Choose your options:").split(',')]

    if not set(choice)-set(['1','2','3','4']): # check for valid choices
        print("Enter valid choices\n")
        continue

    if '4' in choice: loop = 0 # you want to break out, after executing the next loop

    for ts, buf in pcap:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ET_TYPE_IP:
            continue
        ip = eth.data
        data = {'1':str(ip.ver), '2':str(dpkt.ip.IP_HDR_LEN), '3':str(ip.len)}

        ff = ','.join([data[i] for i in choice if i in data.keys()])
        print ff
```

You may also want to check whether all choices are valid or not. For example, user can enter `1,2,34,42,4` as input.

Comment: when i am trying to put this in csv it printing single word in single column by using this code     c.writerow(', '.join([dict[i] for i in choice if i in dict.keys()]))

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are trying to say. Do you mean the `writerow` function does not print as desired? What does it print and what should it print?

Comment: print command is working fine but when am trying to write same output in csv, it is printing the selected option headers one alphabet per column. Like 'V' in first column,' e' in second, 'r' in second but expected output is Ver in first column, HeaderLength in second respectively for CSV

Comment: `writerow()` needs an iterable. Use `c.writerow([dict[i] for i in choice if i in dict.keys()])`. You just need to pass the list of column names.

Comment: its working but the     c.writerow(ff.split(',')) skipping the first column and    c.writerow([dict[i] for i in choice if i in dict.keys()]) strating from first column of csv ... This issue can be resolved anyhow?

Comment: Just add an empty string `''` at the start of the list. Like `c.writerow(['']+[dict[i] for i in choice if i in dict.keys()])`.

Comment: There is one issue, when i use print ff command it print ',' for the first value, There is any solution that can not print comma for the first value?

Comment: comma for any first value will be removed
, 4,  20,  60
, 4,  20,  60

Comment: Check edit. I made a new loop for you. Make some changes according to your need.